# How to view the content of recovered.edit of hbase?

Tags: hbase

It seems that one dirty data in WAL trigger an exception which cause all the RegionServers in the cluster down. I want to see the content of the data in recovered.edit. How can I do that? 
PS
hbase version: 0.98.20

Answer (score 0):

recovered.edits has WAL format, try to use `bin/hbase hlog` shell command. More info can be found [here](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hlog_tool.prettyprint).